# Node JS Pug template loop errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, ejs

In a pug template, I tried to print  all errors from the error array (if it is defined) with the block of code below:

```
if errors !== "undefined"
    each item in errors
        .msgError Error: 
            = item.msg
else
    div success!
```

It works as expected if the array "errors" is defined. However, I don't know why even if the array "errors" is not defined, it still goes inside the true branch and prints the items of the array and then I got this:

```
messages.pug:2 1| if errors !== "undefined" > 2| each item in errors 3| .msgError Error: 4| = item.msg 5| else Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

If I write it as a multiline javascript block like this:

```
-
    if errors !== "undefined"
        each item in errors
            .msgError Error: 
                = item.msg
    else
        console.log(errors)
```

I got this error:

```
Unexpected token (106:3)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (106:3)
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around undefined.

"undefined" and undefined mean different things. One is a string and the other is the value undefined.

```
if errors !== undefined
    each item in errors
        .msgError Error: 
            = item.msg
else
    div success!
```